# OpenAirInterface EURECOM: how to run mme

Tags: telecommunication, lte

we are trying to run OAI (https://gitlab.eurecom.fr/oai/openair-cn) on our machine
I have run hss, psgw w/o any issues.

But i can't start mme

`./run_mme` returns error:

`Initializing OAI Logging
Initializing MSC logs
Initializing MSC logs Done
Function s6a_init (&mme_config) has failed
returning 22`

how to get more details information about error? `-v 2` does not work

hss peer is configured in mme config.

/etc/hosts contain reocrds for yang and hss too

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

The issue is related to hostname, but you don't need to set the hostname to yang. You should edit the following line in /usr/local/etc/oai/freeDiameter/mme_fd.conf file:

Identity = "yang.openair4G.eur";

Replace "yang" with your hostname and the problem would be solved! :)

Answer (score 1):

well, i have found issue. hostname was wrong. it should be `yang`.

i will find a way to change mme settings